# How can I fix this button

Tags: javascript, html, performance

When I click on any button it shows same first button output. How can I fix it. I want it be different when I click on different button it should display same output that button has. I want it to be on my website.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("out");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#out {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
.output:hover{
    background: black;
}
.output{
    background:#3b4fe4 ;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.out{
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</div>
<div id="out">
This is first output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</div>
<div id="out">
This is second output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</div>
<div id="out">
This is third output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</div>
<div id="out">
This is Fourth output
</div>
```

Comment: id should be unique value, you should not duplicate them, when you select by id it only returns the first element if finds

Comment: That's good. But Is there anyway to use same id for all button or without id these button should work with their own output??

Comment: there are multiple ways of achieving this, one interesting way would be to select nextSibling element and show it

Comment: @TimB.McKinnon Take a look at my answer, I've done it using a single class.

Comment: @TimB.McKinnon Also keep in mind you must accept the answer that was given the first, the answer you accepted is a copy of mine.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee agreed, one you should select the original answer and preferably which ever is is cleaner and solves your problem first, however accusing someone of copying your code is not fair, its a co-incident that our code match, further more if you look closely I posted the logic first in comments above which is even before your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using nextElementSibling:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.output').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const x = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.out {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.output:hover {
  background: black;
}

.output {
  background: #3b4fe4;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.out {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="output">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is first output
</div>
<div class="output">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is second output
</div>
<div class="output">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is third output
</div>
<div class="output">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is Fourth output
</div>
```

Comment: You should see what answers already exist and then post your own, there's no point in spamming the same answer again and again.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee When I started composing this answer other answer wasn't posted.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function myFunction(e) {
      
      if (e.target.style.display === "block") {
        e.target.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        e.target.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
```

and do not give the same id to multiple elements. the id should be always unique

Answer (score 2):

Using the inline event handler, you have to pass `this` to it in order to know which button was clicked. Then, you can use the [`.nextElementSibling` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to target the element that is right after.

Notice that I changed the `id` for a class on the `out` div.

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
  var x = btn.nextElementSibling
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.out {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.output:hover {
  background: black;
}

.output {
  background: #3b4fe4;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.out {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is first output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is second output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is third output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is Fourth output
</div>
```

Another way, that I suggest you to look at for best practices, is to avoid using inline event handlers. See below.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".output").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var x = this.nextElementSibling
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.out {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.output:hover {
  background: black;
}

.output {
  background: #3b4fe4;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.out {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="output">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is first output
</div>
<div class="output">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is second output
</div>
<div class="output">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is third output
</div>
<div class="output">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
  This is Fourth output
</div>
```

Comment: Also I would suggest using `event.target` instead of `this` because `this` would behave differently in case of arrow functions.

Comment: Right.... But as you can see, I did not use any arrow function. Arrow functions are not supported by IE11... So should be used with care.

Comment: Someone copied our answers and that got accepted, LOL!

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee well I didn't COPIED your answer, co-incidentally they match

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee: It's presumptuous to say one "copied" an anwer. Particularly on a simple issue like here. There is no 36 different ways to answer that. - Keep on the good work and take a distance from the rep. points ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Ideally you must see what answers already exist before giving yours, there's no point in spamming the same answer again and again. Anyways reps really arent imp.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee: Again some presomtions... I did not "spam". And I took time to add some advices on best practices. I don't see why I should remove it.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee Agreed, but when I started composing answer other similar answer didn't exist, and I still offer to delete my answer if you wish and request the asker to accept yous answer if that matters so much to you.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I didn't say you copied!

Answer (score 0):

You need a different id for each snippet:

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.out {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
.output:hover{
    background: black;
}
.output{
    background:#3b4fe4 ;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction('out1')">Click me</div>
<div class="out" id="out1">
This is first output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction('out2')">Click me</div>
<div class="out" id="out2">
This is second output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction('out3')">Click me</div>
<div class="out" id="out3">
This is third output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction('out4')">Click me</div>
<div class="out" id="out4">
This is Fourth output
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to find out which button is being clicked, for that you can use `event.target` and then using `nextElementSibling` you can grab the `out` div.

Also use `class` instead of `id` when you need to apply similar behavior to multiple elements, because `ids` ought to be unique.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  var btn = e.target;
  var x = btn.nextElementSibling;
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.out {
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
.output:hover{
    background: black;
}
.output{
    background:#3b4fe4 ;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
This is first output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
This is second output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
This is third output
</div>
<div class="output" onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me</div>
<div class="out">
This is Fourth output
</div>
```